# How can I copy a Google drive folder and remove Google drive association?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to copy a folder from Google drive and paste it somewhere else on my hard drive. When I do this, the folder icon looks like the folder is still associated with Google drive. How can I copy a Google drive folder and remove Google drive association?

Comment: What OS are you using? It's probably just a matter of removing the custom icon from the folder which you can do via Explorer/Finder.

Comment: Windows 64bit 8.1 pro

Comment: This question was also posted by someone else in the google drive forum here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/hHSCE2ZXkQY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a desktop.ini file in each directory and subdirectory that I copied from Google drive. When I deleted the desktop.ini files, the Google drive association was cleaned up.

Comment: Your answer is the correct one. The one in the google forums was way off. Thanks for sharing your findings.